# Not all points being written to InfluxDB using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-2, influxdb-python

I'm using InfluxDB OSS 2.7 and using the influxdb_client Python library to write data. Right now I am attempting to write a lot of data taken in close intervals to the database, but a lot of the points end up not being written.

```
import os
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time

DELAY = 0.1

#create influx client and write api and org
org = "ORG"
client = InfluxDBClient(url="URL", token="TOKEN", org=org)
writeAPI = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)

points = []

for i in range(21):
    nums = [random.random(),random.random(),random.random()]
    current_time = datetime.now()
    for num, field in zip(nums,["Field1","Field2","Field3"]):
        points.append(Point("MEASUREMENT").tag("DeviceName","DEVICE").field(field,num).time(current_time.astimezone()))
    time.sleep(DELAY)

writeAPI.write("BUCKET",org,points)
```

The code above simulates my use case, I am collecting data in groups of 3 where each group is very close to one another. When I have a very small delay between groups, not all of the points get written. I am confused about this for two main reasons.

1. All the points get written when I use a large delay, even though I am writing the entire list at the same time regardless of the delay.
2. When most of the points don't get written, there are always one or two groups of 3 that get written. There is never a partial group.

Any ideas for how I can fix this? Is there something I'm missing regarding how InfluxDB handles writes?

Comment: Are you sure this is an accurate simulation of your actual code?  The actual values being appended to `points` are not `Point` objects -- they are the result of `.time(current_time.astimezone())`.  And `current_time` does not change in the for loop, so I would think you just end up with a list of identical time strings...

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for the response. The values being written to points are all Point objects. The .time, .field, and .tag functions of Point objects all return Point objects. The current_time changes as well. It is by design that it only changes in the outer for loop. In my actual code I am taking measurements in groups of 3 all at the same time.